# Extracting C functions signatures for Erlang

Tags: c++, c, function, parsing, erlang

I was wondering what the most suitable tool is for extracting c (and eventually c++) function names, arguments and their types from source code. I would like to use a tool that can be automated as much as possible.

I want to extract the signature types then have the output read by another program written in Erlang. My goal is to use this information to construct the equivalent of the C types/signatures in Erlang (using ei). I would like this process to work for any C file so I can't use any hardcoded stuff.

I have found a lot of tools that look promising like CLang, CScope and ANTLR and so on but I don't know if any of them will work or if there is a better approach out there.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know if any of them will work, you definitely need to be trying them out before you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely there is something better, but if you don't find it:

```
gcc -aux-info output demo.c
sed '/include/d' output
```

Extracts functions form source code skipping standard functions

Comment: I have read about gcc having some flags that will give information about the code. Is there a way to get an XML file as output so that it can be parsed by an Erlang module? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I found this library yesterday through Google. I'm looking into it. Thanks!