# Print out function name in a c file using shell script?

Tags: c, shell

For example, if I have the C files:

```
game.c
int main(){
    //code
    }

hello.c
int something(){
    //code
}
```

How would I get the output to be:

```
/directory/path/game.c
int main()

/directory/path/hello.c
int something()
```

I've already written a for loop to iterate through the files ending in .c in a directory, but am unsure on how to output the function names?

So Im trying to execute a shell script which will read the C files and then output its function names.

```
for file in $(find $1 -type f -name '*.c')
do
    echo $file
    grep -r "what to search for??"

done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get called function name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349761/get-called-function-name-as-string)

Comment: The context is not clear: are you executing the C program and want to output the functions, or are you executing a shell script (which shell?) which is supposed to *read* the uncompiled C source files and print the functions found there?

Comment: Are you trying to list the functions defined in various .c files using a shell script?

Comment: If you are under gcc, `aux-info` in a loop can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17163583/1606345

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear. I'm executing a shell script which is supposed to read all the C files and then print the function names out

Comment: And with `-aux-info` you don't need a for loop...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it seems that OP wants to scan multiple files.

Comment: @KeineLust `gcc -aux-info /dev/stdout *.c`

Comment: OF course... another problem is that it *will* list definitions from includes too...

Comment: Why not show the code for your shell script so we can help with the display?

Comment: Doing this with `grep` or something similar is entirely non-trivial.  There are too many optional bits and pieces in the way functions are written to make it easy.

Comment: This is almost (if not entirely) impossible to achieve with a simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to pull out the function declarations from the files. You can look here: [Regex to pull out C function prototype declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476173/regex-to-pull-out-c-function-prototype-declarations)

If the line matches the regular expression, you can print it.

Comment: I think you’ve missed the point of the question.  The shell script should list the functions defined in the source files.

Comment: Actually I thought that since the user has inserted `//code` inside his 2 functions in the question, he is asking for some code inside the function itself. Thank you for pointing